# How to fix unresolved imports?

Tags: rust

I realise this is a total newbie question, but I can't seem to find an answer in the docs (poor google-fu I guess).  It's my first time trying Rust and I can't figure out how to fix an unresolved import?

Currently I'm doing this in the code:

`use std::io::net::ip::SocketAddr;`

And getting this error:

```
unresolved import `std::io::net::ip::SocketAddr`. Could not find `net` in `std::io`
```

What am I missing?  Do I need to add a dependency in Cargo.toml or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [read the docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/) and figure out where that type is defined.

1. Visit the [documentation for the standard library](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/)
2. Enter `SocketAddr` in the search box
3. Click on the [correct result](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.SocketAddr.html)
4. Note that `SocketAddr` is under `std::net::SocketAddr`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, hopefully this saves someone else a silly misunderstanding!

Comment: Is there an automatic tool like `goimports` for golang?

Answer (score 1):

The `net` package is actually an adjacent package to `io`

You need:

```
std::net::SocketAddr;
```

(see [the api](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.SocketAddr.html))

instead of

```
std::io::net ...
```